# Counting occurrence of character in slice in Go

Tags: c, performance, go

Okay, so I've hit a brick wall.

**Edit:**
Using `bytes.IndexByte()` in my `count()` function makes it run almost twice as fast. `bytes.IndexByte()` is written in assembly instead of Go. Still not C speed, but closer.

I have two programs, one in C and one in Go that both count newlines in a file. Super simple. The C program runs in ~1.5 seconds, the Go in ~4.25 seconds on a 2.4GB file.

Am I hitting Go's speed limit? If so, *what*, exactly, is causing this? I can read C, but I can't read Assembly so comparing the C's asm and the Go's asm doesn't do much to me except show that the Go has ~400 more lines (ignoring the .ascii section).

While I know Go can't match C step-for-step, I wouldn't assume a 4x slowdown.

Ideas?

Here's the cpuprofile of the Go:
[image]

Here's the C (compiled w/ `gcc -Wall -pedantic -O9`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE (16 * 1024)

int
main()
{

    const char *file = "big.txt";
    int fd = open (file, O_RDONLY);
    char buf[BUFFER_SIZE + 1];
    uintmax_t bytes;
    size_t bytes_read;
    size_t lines;

    posix_fadvise (fd, 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL);
    while ((bytes_read = safe_read (fd, buf, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
    {
        char *p = buf;

        // error checking

        while ((p = memchr (p, '\n', (buf + bytes_read) - p)))
          {
            ++p;
            ++lines;
          }
        bytes += bytes_read;
    }
    printf("%zu\n", bytes);
    printf("%zu\n", lines);
    return 0;
}
```

And the Go:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "runtime/pprof"
    "syscall"
)

const (
    POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL = 2

    NewLineByte = '\n' // or 10
    BufferSize  = (16 * 1024) + 1
)

var Buffer = make([]byte, BufferSize)

func fadvise(file *os.File, off, length int, advice uint32) error {
    _, _, errno := syscall.Syscall6(syscall.SYS_FADVISE64, file.Fd(), uintptr(off), uintptr(length), uintptr(advice), 0, 0)
    if errno != 0 {
        return errno
    }
    return nil
}

func count(s []byte) int64 {
    count := int64(0)
    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        if s[i] == NewLineByte {
            count++
        }
    }
    return count
}

func main() {

    file, err := os.Open("big.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var lines int64
    var bytes int64

    fadvise(file, 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL)
    for {

        n, err := file.Read(Buffer)
        if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
            panic(err)
        }

        lines += count(Buffer[:n])
        bytes += int64(n)

        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("%d\n", bytes)
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", lines)
}
```

Comment: Did you try wrapping your file io with package bufio? Additionally: Why not use the counting functionality provided by package bytes?

Comment: @Volker: this should actually be the answer.  Using the `bytes.Count` alone speeds up execution by 2x.  @eric_lagergren, you can look at the implementation of Count in bytes package.

Comment: @Volker the reading isn't the problem. It's the `count()` function. See next reply...

Comment: @sberry, `bytes.Count()` actually ran slower for me. I tried it with my `count()` and `bytes.Count()` and even Go's assembly didn't speed it up.

Comment: Well, actually now it's running still slower but closer. Perhaps I goofed up my tests earlier. Who knows. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what the motivation is other than a drag race, but  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BkKP3naKLi8 describes someone getting speed on a related counting problem by avoiding branching, using a table. You could look for wacky ways to use SSE 4.2 instructions via a .s file (not sure if 6a supports them, though). You really don't need to.

Comment: Maybe the most important observation is that a 4x difference here does not mean a 4x diff everywhere. To see how, say, a Web app would perform, build a little of it out and compare those.

Comment: @twotwotwo The motivation is a drag race. I just need to count bytes as quickly as possible. This will be (and is) the bottleneck of the program -- it's internal use.

Comment: @eric_lagergren I'm not on Intel etc. so can't compare, but here's http://play.golang.org/p/4urJlhL-ZF

Comment: @twotwotwo Mmap is faster than the original, but slower than `bytes.IndexByte()` (roughly 3 seconds)... it took ~10 seconds on the first run, which presumably was loading the file into memory.

Comment: @eric_lagergren Right, now using IndexByte, which is a small gain on my file/machine: http://play.golang.org/p/5l0ppjveVS -- most obvious step from here would be to divide the file into n pieces and go get a count from each, but that's a lot of fuss. (I didn't see any gain from counting *all* byte occurrences in a table to avoid the branch, maybe because the branch is predictable, i.e., most bytes aren't newlines. YMMV.)

Comment: @eric_lagergren Yeah, tiny gain on my (ARM!) machine (on a different file!) by parallelizing: http://play.golang.org/p/j8b-f3qWMu . But, again, though I don't know your domain, life often holds bigger concerns than whether newline counting only runs at 800 MB/s when the file is cached in RAM. If the file isn't cached in real life, CPU time could be swamped by time to read, for instance.

Comment: @twotwotwo True. My only concern is that Go gets as close of speed as C, primarily because I'm looking to swap out the C program with Go. And while two seconds on a 2.5GB file isn't very much, I've been rather bored the last couple nights and this has piqued my interest.

Comment: @twotwotwo Thanks for your help though. Really insightful and that video is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

As far as this is about counting `'\n'` in a file, this code runs in ~1.26 sec (and mostly faster), on a Zorin VM (VMWare Player), 6 GB RAM, 4 Cores (& power is plugged in; because power managers sometimes prevent CPU from consuming battery too fast), Host OS is Windows 8. I am using Go in some real world projects for less than 6 months and I'm a Linux noob too. But I think the problem is calling C from Go and that's much slower than pure Go - I've experienced this in calling some C code, both as `dll` and got compiled with `cgo`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    tstart := time.Now()

    file, err := os.Open(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    done := make(chan bool)
    var cnt int64 = 0
    go func() {
        var Buffer = make([]byte, BufferSize)
        for {
            n, err := file.Read(Buffer)
            if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
                panic(err)
            }

            cnt += count(Buffer[:n])

            if err == io.EOF {
                done <- true
                return
            }
        }
    }()
    <-done
    // should be 5860298 in this case (zorin iso image) & it is.
    fmt.Println(cnt)
    fmt.Printf("%s took %s\n", "counting", time.Since(tstart))
}

func count(s []byte) int64 {
    count := int64(0)
    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        if s[i] == NewLineByte {
            count++
        }
    }
    return count
}

const (
    NewLineByte = '\n' // or 10
    BufferSize  = 32 * 1024
)

var (
    filePath = "/.../zorin-os-9.1-core-64++.iso"
    maxt     int
)

func init() {
    maxt = runtime.NumCPU()
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(maxt)
}
```

Comment: I like it. Unfortunately, on my Linux box (debian 3.16, i3 w/ 8gb ram) it take ~2.5 sec, which is about the same (actually, almost identical) as if it simply used `*os.File.Read()` in a loop. Thanks, though!

Comment: I'm glad it was useful. Again I must assert I'm a *nix noob, but if you are running Mint, I could say I felt Vista all over again! On the other hand Ubuntu was doing great and Zorin is doing even better. I do not know how is that possible, but it should have something to do with optimizing the swap drive and things like that. Zorin installed with default settings (next,next,next,...).

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://play.golang.org/p/5l0ppjveVS) a not too hard and not too slow way, using `bytes.IndexByte` (since you found Go's asm implementation of it helped) and `syscall.Mmap`:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) < 2 {
        log.Fatal("pass filename on command line")
    }
    f, err := os.Open(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("open: ", err)
    }
    stat, err := f.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("stat: ", err)

    }
    data, err := syscall.Mmap(int(f.Fd()), 0, int(stat.Size()), syscall.PROT_READ, syscall.MAP_SHARED)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("mmap: ", err)
    }
    newlines := 0
    for {
        i := bytes.IndexByte(data, 10)
        if i == -1 {
            break
        }
        newlines++
        data = data[i+1:]
    }
    fmt.Println(newlines)
}
```

`Mmap` looks weird, but here it's much as if you'd read the file into a slice, except less resource-intensive thanks to the OS's help.

[You can parallelize the counting](http://play.golang.org/p/j8b-f3qWMu) without too much more work, but I'm not sure that's worth it. (It would not shock me if the gain on `amd64` were zero or negative if, for example, single-core counting were limited by memory bandwidth, but that's not quick for me to test.)