# Reading in very large files

Tags: file, go

I'm trying to read in a file with 200+ columns and 1000+ rows. I use the following code:

```
var result []string

file, err := os.Open("t8.txt")
if (err != nil) {
  fmt.Println(err)
}
defer file.Close()
scan := bufio.NewScanner(file)
for scan.Scan() {
  result = append(result, scan.Text())

}


fmt.Println(scan.Err()) //token too long
```

However, when I print out the results, all I get is the first line because it says the token is too long. When I try it on smaller files, it works fine. Is there a way in Go that I could scan in large files?

Comment: **Never** ignore `error` return values! (Both from `os.Open` and check `scan.Err()` after the loop as well).

Comment: I didn't know they had a scan.Err() as well, but now I see that it returns "token too long."

Comment: When I want to read the whole file anyway, sometimes I just use [`syscall.Mmap`](http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Mmap), like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28592330/2714852).

Comment: Yes, [`const bufio.MaxScanTokenSize = 64*1024`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#MaxScanTokenSize). So you either need to use smaller tokens (e.g. a split function to tokenize on columns) or use a different reading method. BTW, do you want/need the whole contents in memory or are just doing per-line processing?

Answer (score 6):

As already pointed out by @Dave C in the comments you are running into MaxScanTokenSize = 64 * 1024

To get around that limitation, use bufio.Reader which has a ReadString(delim byte) method which seems appropriate for your case.

From the Scanner go doc (specifically the last sentence):

> Scanner provides a convenient interface for reading data such as a
>   file of newline-delimited lines of text. Successive calls to the Scan
>   method will step through the 'tokens' of a file, skipping the bytes
>   between the tokens. The specification of a token is defined by a split
>   function of type SplitFunc; the default split function breaks the
>   input into lines with line termination stripped. Split functions are
>   defined in this package for scanning a file into lines, bytes,
>   UTF-8-encoded runes, and space-delimited words. The client may instead
>   provide a custom split function.
>
> Scanning stops unrecoverably at EOF, the first I/O error, or a token
>   too large to fit in the buffer. When a scan stops, the reader may have
>   advanced arbitrarily far past the last token. Programs that need more
>   control over error handling or large tokens, or must run sequential
>   scans on a reader, should use bufio.Reader instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can change default buff:

```
sc := bufio.NewScanner(r)
buf := make([]byte, 0, 64*1024)
sc.Buffer(buf, 1024*1024)
```